# `as.Date()` returns `NA` instead of Date object for string "2012-01"

Tags: r

This returns `NA` instead of a Date object `2012-01`.

```
as.Date(
    x = "2012-01",
    format = "%Y-%m"
)
```

Why does this return `NA` and what must I change to make it return a Date object representing January 2012?

Comment: `zoo::as.yearmon('2012-01')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates need to have a year, month, *and* day component.  Assuming you were OK with the first of the month representing a given month, you could use:

```
x <- "2012-01"
d <- paste0(x, "-01")
as.Date(d, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```